# Restart ESXi from remote while having a PSOD

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-server

I wondered if it is possible to access some functions of a ESXi Server over the network, while the server has a PSOD. 
The Server is running ESXi 5.1.

The server cannot be pinged, but is there some kind of network debug function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [debug from the console](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004250) and generate a crash dump.

Ideally, you have some sort of [out-of-band management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management) of your physical ESXi host like IPMI, DRAC or ILO. If not, you should :)

Otherwise, you would need to physically be in front of the system to get out of your PSOD state.

---

In general, VMware should not PSOD. There have been [some specific and dangerous issues](https://serverfault.com/questions/580598/vmware-lockup-cpu-spike/580608#580608) that impacted certain builds of ESXi, but most VMware issues can be traced back to a need for updates/patching.

Can you provide more detail on your real issue? Version and build of ESXi, hardware, etc.

Comment: How do I see if any OOB management is present? It is an Intel S5000PAL

Comment: There's nothing that can help your existing situation unless the IPMI on this Intel system board is present and configured.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use the server's out of band management interface (IPMI, iDRAC, ILO, etc.) to reboot the server.

Answer (score 4):

> is there some kind of network debug function?

No - you need to iLO/DRAC/send-someone to restart the machine.